# How to handle orientation change smoothly with camerax and TextureView?

Tags: android-camerax

I'm trying to get a smooth transition on orientation change, like stock camera app does (icons rotate, camera view does not blink).

I already done the icon rotation part by setting `ROTATION_ANIMATION_CROSSFADE` and manually start animations on activity creation.

But my `TextureView` (where camerax is rendering) is recreated on config changes so it fades to black on orientation change.

How can I avoid the recreation of the view? Should I handle the config change by myself?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to your activity in the Manifest file. Then, the activity will not be recreated on device rotation. After that, handle the orientation change on your own. 
I prefer doing that with a OrientationChangeListener.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
       //handle orientation change
        orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(getActivity(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                updateUi(orientation); //rotate ui elements on orientation change
                videoCapture?.setTargetRotation(getOrientation(orientationHint)) //notify the capture session about the orientation change
            }
        };
        orientationEventListener.enable();
}
```

The getOrientation() method returns one integer from the Surface constant integers: Surface.ROTATION_0, Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180 or Surface.ROTATION_270.

Also note that you need to disable the orientationEventListener in the onPause() method.

EDIT:

```
** Helper function that gets the rotation of a [Display] in degrees */
 fun getOrientation(rotation: Int?) = when (rotation) {
      0 -> Surface.ROTATION_0
      90 -> Surface.ROTATION_90
      180 -> Surface.ROTATION_180
      270 -> Surface.ROTATION_270
      else -> Surface.ROTATION_0
 }
```

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait" also lock the system ui (status bar position and back arrow navigation orientation for example). That's why I dont want to lock the screen orientation.

Comment: Yes, it does. But if you want the status bar and the navigation to switch, this means the activity will have to be recreated. It is common in camera apps that the system ui is 'locked' when rotating the device. Check out your phone's native camera app, the UI remains locked while rotating the device. It's the only way to keep the activity alive and not have that black screen while the ui is being recreated.

Comment: Yep the activity is recreate, with a fade animation instead of the rotate animation and the land layout matches exactly the portrait layout so it looks like nothing move (then I start rotate icons to the correct orientation).. But the preview goes black during recreation...

No, that is wrong, google camera app is not lock in portrait, system UI moves and the preview follow the rotation perfectly. I just saw that opencamera do the same, I will check the code.

Comment: My bad, opencamera is locked in landscape orientation.

Comment: @deluxe1 can you clarify how do you convert orientation into rotation?

Comment: @art check the updated answer for the getOrientation() method

Comment: `onOrientationChanged` returns value from -1 to 359, your function `getOrientation` doesn't make any sense