# Android camera rotation handling for preview by Pixel camera and Samsung camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have been researching and trying to improve camera UX for my app. I noticed that on Pixel 4a as well as on Samsung Galaxy Active Tab, app handles rotation without closing the preview or any rotation animation. But the notification and swipe up gesture for navigation bar does orient the correct way based on device is being held in landscape or portrait.

Is there anyone who has been successful in getting the default camera behavior?

Based on many posts on here, Google camera sample apps, OpenCamera, etc standard practice is to either lock the camera in portrait or landscape based on how device will be used most of the time by using the following in manifest:

`android:screenOrientation="portrait`

Or register for configuration changes in manifest and then manage it in activity with the following snippet:

```
//manifest
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    ...

//in-activity
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // rotate buttons using newConfig.orientation value
}
```

I have tried both of the above options, setting it portrait is what I do right now but that will lock notification pull down and swipe up navigation gesture to natural display orientation of device.

Handling config changes on my own works but that leads to preview closing for short duration (probably in milliseconds) before transitioning to right orientation but still undesirable specially when comparing Pixel camera or Samsung camera.

Some posts that I have come across which led me to posting this:

- [How to handle orientation change smoothly with camerax and TextureView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145628/how-to-handle-orientation-change-smoothly-with-camerax-and-textureview)
- [How to create a BottomBar as StickyBottomCaptureLayout in camera2 Android api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612692/how-to-create-a-bottombar-as-stickybottomcapturelayout-in-camera2-android-api)

And tested behavior from these sample code as well:
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Basic

At last my suspicion is that either it's some documentation piece that's not directly associated with camera but Activity lifecycle that I might be missing which could help achieve this or perhaps Google and Samsung have specific API or manifest tag they use to manage this.